# clarification on supervised LDA package in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I'm using [LDA package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lda/) in R for topic modeling and get confused on the parameter setting in the function `slda.em`.

`slda.em(documents, K, vocab, num.e.iterations, num.m.iterations, alpha,
eta, annotations, params, variance, logistic = FALSE, lambda = 10,
regularise = FALSE, method = "sLDA", trace = 0L, MaxNWts=3000)`

From my understanding, sLDA model can fit and predict response values for new documents. So I am wondering if the `annotation` represents response/label in slda? If not what does annotation mean? And which parameter should I regard as response? Thank you!